# UIDatePicker in IOS 14 showing background tabBar in keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

When using date picker in keyboard in IOS 14 getting this kind of output. It is not overlaying my tab bar controller in back. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the view in your current UIWindow which is accessible through root view of your ViewController like this:

```
self.view.window?.addSubview(calendarView)
```

And then make it overlay all other UIViews, like this:

```
self.view.window?.bringSubview(toFront: calendarView)
```

Comment: It worth mentioning that since iOS 13.4, there is preferredDatePickerStyle in UIDatePicker which you can set the style with inline, wheels, compact and automatic modes.

Comment: here the calendar view i am implementing is in input source of text field that is in keyboard and i think your method will. bring my seperately implemented view to front. Am i right?

Comment: By the i found a roundway, i changed the style of datepicker to wheels and it is fine now. By the way if you have any suggestions regarding this please share